# ')' expected (toclose '(' at line 453) near 'end'

Tags: lua

I can't find where the ) is supposted to go. Please help me with this. Thank you :)

```
ShootButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
local Person = NameShoot.Text
local A_1 = "right"
local A_2 = Vector3.new(-304.910004, 792.936279, -1810.74658)
local A_3 = Vector3.new(-321.448303, 792.981812, -1801.7301)
local A_4 = 0.0094182577133179
local A_5 = 2000
local A_6 =     
game:GetService("Workspace").TopPiece.Suit.RightHand.Thruster.Exhaust
local A_7 = game:GetService("Workspace")[Person].Suit.RightUpperArm.Union
local Event = 
game:GetService("Players").TopPiece.Backpack.suitControl.Assets.Events.fireR
epulsor
Event:InvokeServer(A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, A_5, A_6, A_7)
end
end)
```

Comment: It's easier to figure out where parentheses (and `end`) belong if you add more indentation to your code.

Answer (score 4):

Now I dont know lua, but my guess is change this at the end

```
end
end)
```

To

```
end)
```

It looks like you're ending the function with the first end, but closing the parenthesis on the second end when the function is already done.

Answer (score 2):

If you indent your code consistently then you should get less of these types of issues...

```
ShootButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(
  function()
    local Person = NameShoot.Text
    local A_1 = "right"
    local A_2 = Vector3.new(-304.910004, 792.936279, -1810.74658)
    local A_3 = Vector3.new(-321.448303, 792.981812, -1801.7301)
    local A_4 = 0.0094182577133179
    local A_5 = 2000
    local A_6 = game:GetService("Workspace").TopPiece.Suit.RightHand.Thruster.Exhaust
    local A_7 = game:GetService("Workspace")[Person].Suit.RightUpperArm.Union
    local Event = game:GetService("Players").TopPiece.Backpack.suitControl.Assets.Events.fireRepulsor
    Event:InvokeServer(A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, A_5, A_6, A_7)
  end
)
```

It becomes obvious that there is one `end` for the `function` and one closing parenthesis for the `Connect` function call.

You can also do this...

```
ShootButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
  local Person = NameShoot.Text
  local A_1 = "right"
  local A_2 = Vector3.new(-304.910004, 792.936279, -1810.74658)
  local A_3 = Vector3.new(-321.448303, 792.981812, -1801.7301)
  local A_4 = 0.0094182577133179
  local A_5 = 2000
  local A_6 = game:GetService("Workspace").TopPiece.Suit.RightHand.Thruster.Exhaust
  local A_7 = game:GetService("Workspace")[Person].Suit.RightUpperArm.Union
  local Event = game:GetService("Players").TopPiece.Backpack.suitControl.Assets.Events.fireRepulsor
  Event:InvokeServer(A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, A_5, A_6, A_7)
end)
```

.. but I personally find that the first format is clearer.